# How can simplify the nested if condition in excel formula

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

The excel formula is,

```
=IF(OR(B42="First Proof",B42="Revised First Proof"),IF(WEEKDAY(J42-1)=1,J42-2,J42-1),IF(OR(B42="Revises2",B42="Revises3",B42="Revises4",B42="Revises5",B42="Revises6",B42="Revises7"),IF(WEEKDAY(Q42-1)=1,Q42-2,Q42*1),IF(B42="Revises1",IF(WEEKDAY(J42-1)=1,J42-2,J42-1),IF(B42="Typescript",IF(WEEKDAY(J42-1)=1,J42-2,J42-1),IF(B42="Finals",IF(WEEKDAY(J42-1)=1,J42-2,J42-1),IF(OR(B42="ELDs",B42="Post Conversion",B42="Revised ELDs"),"NA"))))))
```

Please help me to reduce the formula length.

Comment: Have you tried using Switch? This may reduce it. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-function-47ab33c0-28ce-4530-8a45-d532ec4aa25e

Comment: @XOIOX - Woah! I was about to say switch case is VBA only. Didn't know about the function, thanks for that!  OP - Could you just check for "Proof"? Also, it would help a lot if we could see some sample data, and sample expected output from your formula.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @XOIOX, its depends on few cell values which is defined already.

Comment: fwiw, OR statements like `(OR(B42="First Proof",B42="Revised First Proof")` can be written as `(OR(B42={"First Proof","Revised First Proof"})` which is a few characters less and (to my eyes) a little more readable.

Comment: @Jeeped, thanks, its works fine. as well, is it possible to reduce this line `IF(OR(B42="Revises2",B42="Revises3",B42="Revises4",B42="Revises5",B42="Revises6",B42="Revises7")` to `IF(OR(B42="Revises*")` or `IF(OR(B42="Revises[2-7]")`

Comment: @Darious so what hapoened when you tested with revises* ?

Comment: Try `IF(LEFT(B42, 7)="Revises", ...` but you will match Revises, Revises1 and Revises8.

Comment: Maybe `IF(AND(LEFT(B42, 7)="Revises", OR(RIGHT(B42)={"2","3","4","5","6","7"})), ...`

Comment: @Jeeped, Thanks for giving a valuable solution to reduce the formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget that you can use alt+enter and spaces to format multi-line formulas and improve readability.

```
=IF(or(right(B42, 11)="first proof", or(b42={"revises1", "typescript", "finals"})), J42-1-(WEEKDAY(J42, 2)=1),
 IF(AND(LEFT(B42, 7)="Revises", OR(RIGHT(B42)={"2","3","4","5","6","7"})), Q42-(WEEKDAY(Q42, 2)=1)*2,
 IF(or(b42={"elds", "post conversion", "revised elds"}), "NA", "")))
```

Reduced from 437 characters to ~275 characters and the `OR(RIGHT(B42)={"2","3","4","5","6","7"})` isn't even necessary as Revises1 has already been checked for.

Comment: Thanks for the brief explanation.